# Вылетает программа при попытке вывести некторые аргументы в Log. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Я создавал приложение, в нём есть элемент `"Number (Decimal)"`, c `id` `result_editText`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел сделать его недоступным для изменения после некоторого момента, для этого написал

```
result_editText.setEnabled(false);
result_editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

Но при компиляции и запуске на устройстве приложение вылетало (оно скмплировалось, вывелось значком на рабочий стол, но при запуске вылетает)

Я решил проверить что не так, поэтому переписал код таким образом:

```
//result_editText.setEnabled(false);
//result_editText.setCursorVisible(false);
Log.d("tag", result_editText.text.toString())
```

Но проблема осталась. Можете подсказать в чём может быть дело?

P.S. `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.* импортирован`

P.P.S. Закоментировав обращение к result_editText программа работает полностью корректно.

P.P.P.S. Вот xml представление этого эл-а

[image: 1]

Comment: Вы уверены в том, что верно ищете его? Проверьте правильность написания идентификатора.

Comment: Да, я уверен. IDE автокомплитнуло название.

Comment: Тогда посмотрите, какую ошибку он выдаёт.

Comment: Ну для начала хорошо бы приложить лог ошибки и указать на какой строчке оно падает

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: result_editText must not be null` - вот код ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете Kotlin, вам нет необходимости вызывать `findViewById()`. Но тут нужно помнить 2 вещи.

В Activity ваш макет раздувается в методе `onCreate()` вызовом метода `setContentView()` и сразу же после него вы можете использовать синтетики. Если вы попытаетесь воспользоваться синтетиком раньше чем вызовется этот метод - получите `IllegalStateException`.

Частой ошибкой бывает аналогичная попытка использования синтетиков в Fragment-ах. Так как в Java вы присваиваете значение переменным в `onCreateView()` многие новички пытаются это же сделать и с помощью синтетиков в Kotlin-е, не  совсем понимая как это работает.

Поясню:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_vew);
    return view;
}
```

Как видите тут для того чтоб получить доступ к View через `findViewById()` вы используете View которую уже раздули с помощью `LayoutInflater`. Потому вы имеет доступ к этим id.

Но в Kotlin-е синтетик в этом месте программы еще не может получить доступ к этой ссылке. Я лично не пробовал, но уверен, что если вы обратитесь к вашей переменной в этом месте через `view.textView` это сработает.

Но более логичным подходом будет начинать использовать элементы XML уже в методе `onViewCreated()` или позже. Этот метод говорит, что View уже создана и готова к работе.

Я думаю ваша проблема находится здесь.